# How to measure skin-electrode impedence of dry eeg electrodes without an impedence analyzer?

Tags: impedance, biopotential, eeg

I understand how to measure the impedance with an impedance analyzer, but I'm curious if it's possible to create a impedance measurement system on some kind of wearable with eeg electrodes. What's the engineering behind doing something like this?

Comment: AD5933 - AD5934 Analog Device subsystem ...